# Forcing Mathematica to not assume symmetry of partial derivatives?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I ran the following code:

```
DF = D[F[x, y, z], {{x, y, z}}];
HF = D[F[x, y, z], {{x, y, z}, 2}];

HF // MatrixForm
ResourceFunction["CofactorMatrix"][HF] // MatrixForm
```

In the first column of the second matrix, it will appear:

> $$F^{(0,0,2)}(x,y,z) F^{(0,2,0)}(x,y,z)-\color{red}{F^{(0,1,1)}(x,y,z)^2}$$

Ie: It seems to be assuming that [symmetry of second derivatives.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetry_of_second_derivatives) Is there an "easy" way of forcing it to not assume it? I know I could code this by manually writing the derivative in y, and then in z, and another version with the derivative first in z and then in y but I'm wondering if there is some easier way.

Comment: "I know I could code this by manually writing the derivative in y, and then in z"-- I can't even get the right answer with `Limit`: `d[x_, c_][f_] :=  Limit[First@Differences[f /. {{x -> c}, {x -> c + h}}]/h, h -> 0];

Assuming[{{x, y, a, b} \[Element] Reals}, Piecewise[{{x y (x^2 - y^2)/(x^2 + y^2), x != 0 && y != 0}, {0, x == 0 && y == 0}}] // d[x, a] // d[y, b] ]`

Comment: @MichaelE2 I thought I could make `D[D[f[x, y], x], y]´ and ´D[D[f[x, y], y], x]` but it seems it computes it in the same order, ie: It shows the same symbol $f^{(1,1)}(x,y)$.

Comment: [Symmetry of second derivatives](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetry_of_second_derivatives). [Hessian matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hessian_matrix).  A side note: it is bad practice to start your symbol names with an upper case Latin letter because of possible collisions with Mathematica's own symbols.